# Starting Tomcat6 - "/usr/share/tomcat6/bin/startup.sh" **OR** "/etc/init.d/tomcat6 start"?

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat6

What is the difference between starting **TOMCAT6** on an Ubuntu system using the following methods:

> ```
> /usr/share/tomcat6/bin/startup.sh
> ```

> ```
> sudo /etc/init.d/tomcat6 start
> ```

Comment: Most likely better for [Superuser](http://superuser.com) or [Ubuntu](http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either one.  I use startup.sh when I need to manage tomcat myself.  I  use the /etc/init.d script when I want to run tomcat as a daemon/service.

Answer (score 2):

The init.d script is the startup script for the system service, that internally should call to `/usr/share/tomcat6/bin/startup.sh`, that should be the tomcat start script.

If you want to start tomcat when the machine is booted, you should use the `update-rc.d` command to add it to the list of services that will be started at boot time.